# MySql Error 1005 erno:105 Can't create table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
drop table if exists patient;
drop table if exists pan;
drop table if exists device;
drop table if exists sensor;
drop table if exists actuator;
drop table if exists wears;
drop table if exists connects;
drop table if exists period;
drop table if exists reading;
drop table if exists setting;
drop table if exists lives;
drop table if exists municipality;

create table patient
    (patient_name varchar(255),
     patient_number integer(10),
     patient_address varchar(255),
     primary key(patient_number));

create table pan
    (pan_domain varchar(255),
     pan_phone integer(9),
     primary key(pan_domain));

create table device
    (device_snum integer(10),
     device_manuf varchar(255),
     device_description varchar(255),
     primary key(device_snum, device_manuf));

create table municipality
    (municipality_nut4code integer(10),
     municipality_name varchar(255),
     primary key(municipality_nut4code));

create table period
    (period_start time,
     period_end time,
     primary key(period_start, period_end));

create table sensor
    (sensor_snum integer(10),
     sensor_manuf varchar(255),
     sensor_units varchar(255),
     primary key(sensor_snum, sensor_manuf),
     foreign key(sensor_snum) references device(device_snum),
     foreign key(sensor_manuf) references device(device_manuf));

create table actuator
    (actuator_snum integer(10),
     actuator_manuf varchar(255),
     actuator_units varchar(255),
     primary key(actuator_snum, actuator_manuf),
     foreign key(actuator_snum) references device(device_snum),
     foreign key(actuator_manuf) references device(device_manuf));

create table wears
    (wears_start time,
     wears_end time,
     wears_patient integer(10),
     wears_pan varchar(255),
     primary key(wears_start, wears_end, wears_patient),
     foreign key(wears_start) references period(period_start),
     foreign key(wears_end) references period(period_end),
     foreign key(wears_patient) references patient(patient_number),
     foreign key(wears_pan) references pan(pan_domain));   

create table connects
    (connects_start time,
     connects_end time,
     connects_snum integer(10),
     connects_manuf varchar(255),
     connects_pan varchar(255),
     primary key(connects_start, connects_end, connects_snum,    connects_manuf),
     foreign key(connects_start) references period(period_start),
     foreign key(connects_end) references period(period_end),
     foreign key(connects_snum) references device(device_snum),
     foreign key(connects_manuf) references device(device_manuf),
     foreign key(connects_pan) references pan(pan_domain));

 create table reading
    (reading_snum integer(10),
     reading_manuf varchar(255),
     reading_datetime date,
     reading_value numeric(10,2),
     primary key(reading_snum, reading_manuf, reading_datetime),
     foreign key(reading_snum) references sensor(sensor_snum),
     foreign key(reading_manuf) references sensor(sensor_manuf));

create table setting
    (setting_snum integer(10),
     setting_manuf varchar(255),
     setting_datetime date,
     setting_value numeric(10,2),
     primary key(setting_snum, setting_manuf, setting_datetime),
     foreign key(setting_snum) references actuator(actuator_snum),
     foreign key(setting_manuf) references actuator(actuator_manuf));

create table lives
    (lives_start time,
     lives_end time,
     lives_patient integer(10),
     lives_municipality integer(10),
     primary key(lives_start, lives_end, lives_patient),
     foreign key(lives_start) references period(period_start),
     foreign key(lives_end) references period(period_end),
     foreign key(lives_patient) references patient(patient_number),
     foreign key(lives_municipality) references    municipality(municipality_nut4code));
```

When I try to create this database on MySQL I get an error saying ERROR 1005 (HY000) can't create table ***** (errno: 150). The tables that can't be created are the ones which have foreign keys. I already checked the data types and that the references match a primary key of a previously created table.
I don't get the error. Can someone help?

Comment: Maybe your MySQL server has a default engine of MYISAM? Try adding `ENGINE=InnoDB` to all table definitions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have composite keys in the tables you're referencing, you should make the foreign key composite as well. For example:

```
create table sensor
    (sensor_snum integer(10),
     sensor_manuf varchar(255),
     sensor_units varchar(255),
     primary key(sensor_snum, sensor_manuf),
     foreign key(sensor_snum, sensor_manuf) references device(device_snum, device_manuf));
```

Also, if you have two tables with the same foreign key, you need to give names to the foreign keys. All foreign keys need to have different names, and if you don't give a name explicitly, MySQL generates the name based just on the columns in the foreign key, and you'll end up with duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I made te foreign keys all composite and some of the tables where indeed created, but tables "wears", "connects" and "lives" where still not created.
As for the duplicated names, I had already written all the names in a unique way to avoid that.

Comment: Got it! Turns out I made a dumb mistake when making the foreign keys composite.
Thank you very much!